# Need to create bivalent chloropleth map from latitude/longitude and two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geospatial, r-sf

My manager asked me to create a bivalent chloropleth map in R from a csv file that contains latitude/longitude data and two variables. I’ve tried to use this tutorial and this stack overflow post but have been unsuccessful – the plot comes up completely empty.

This is an example of what my manager is looking for: https://jech.bmj.com/content/jech/75/6/496/F1.large.jpg

I’ve tried to use [this tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biscale/vignettes/biscale.html) and [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72591794/create-a-bivariate-choropleth-map-using-tidycensus) but have been unsuccessful – the plot comes up completely empty.

Below is a mini reproducible version of the data.

```
df <- data.frame(Region = c(1001, 1003, 1005, 1007),
                 ID = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 latitude = c(32.53953, 30.72775, 31.86826, 32.99642),
                 longitude = c(-86.64408, -87.72207, -85.38713, -87.12511),
                 variable_1 = c(0.3465, 0.3028, 0.4168, 0.3866),
                 variable_2 = c(0.44334, 0.45972, 0.46996, 0.44406))
```

I am not well-versed in mapping (or in R, frankly) so I would be deeply appreciative of any help this community could provide. Even understanding what additional data I need to create a bivalent plot would be really helpful.

Thank you and please let me know of any additional info I could provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve such choropleth map. First you need to load/install the necessary packages:

```
library(biscale)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
```

Then you need to compute the `bi_class` between the two variables that will be used to map each group (low,medium,high) for each combination.

```
df = bi_class(df, x= variable_1, y=variable_2, style="quantile", dim = 3)
```

> As per documention on the [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biscale/vignettes/biscale.html) you can change the `dim` argument to create a 2x2 or 4x4 matrix

Then for what I saw within your data you are looking into counties in Alabama. For this you can look into the [tigris package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tigris/readme/README.html). (not limited to counties)

```
Al_county <- tigris::counties(state = "Alabama", cb = TRUE) %>% st_as_sf()
```

Finally, you can merge your data frame into the imported data frame with `GEOID` and `Region`. Make sure to add a 0 in from of your 'Region' if it's missing:

| `GEOID` (in imported data) | `Region` (in your df) |
| --- | --- |
| 01001 | 1001 |
| 01003 | 1003 |
| 01005 | 1005 |
| 01007 | 1007 |

```
df$Region = paste0("0", df$Region) # Add 0 in front of Region values
Al_county = Al_county %>% left_join(df, by= c("GEOID"= "Region")) # Join the 2 data frames
```

Now the data is ready to be plotted and you can follow the documentation from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biscale/vignettes/biscale.html)

```
map = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = Al_county, aes(fill=bi_class))+
  bi_scale_fill(pal = "GrPink", dim = 3)+
  labs(subtitle = "Var 1 and Var 2 in Alabama") +
  bi_theme()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")

legend <- bi_legend(pal = "GrPink", dim = 3, xlab = "Higher Var 1 ", ylab = "Higher Var 2 ",  size = 8)

finalPlot <- ggdraw() + draw_plot(map, 0, 0, 1, 1) + draw_plot(legend, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.15)

finalPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! I will work through your recommendations!

Comment: Glad I could help you improve your skills! If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.